# How to call the sub that called this sub from a future sub

Tags: vb.net, class, stack-trace

Boy oh boy, that title is confusing ay!

This is best explained with an example.. here's what I want to happen.

```
Dim m as sub

Public sub alg1()
    call alg2()
End sub

Public sub alg2()
    m = alg1
    call alg3()
End sub

Public sub alg3()
    call m
End sub
```

So I start running my code at alg1. alg1 calls alg2, which makes a note of who called it (I'm thinking with stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name) and then stores that in a local variable and then alg2 goes on to call alg3. alg3 calls whichever sub is stored in the local variable m.

Now my situation is a little more complicated since alg1 is in a different class to alg2, but in theory all I'm trying to do is make a cross class call to a sub that's defined at runtime. Is there any way to store a sub like this?

Comment: Downvote within the first 30seconds.. that's got to be some sort of record. Any advice on how to improve the question (or why it was downvoted)?

Comment: look into Delegates. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172880.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t38cb9x.aspx

Comment: If alg1 and alg2 are in different class, where is alg3? Even if you know the function, you'll still need a reference to the object. Can you pass these as arguments? In your example, you will have a infinite loop, how will you get out of it? Could you do this with events and delegate instead?

Comment: @Jeremy thanks, this seems to be the sort of thing I'm looking for, I'm still at a bit of a loss as to how I can use them for my purpose... but I think I just need to wrap my head around this for a while!

Comment: essentially you can use a variable to call a function, so you need to pass in a delegate variable in a function to call it later on. Do you have a higher level description of the actual problem you are trying to solve? You may be looking at it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example should work with a small change of `Action` and `AddressOf`

```
Dim m As Action

Public Sub alg1()
    Call alg2()
End Sub

Public Sub alg2()
    m = AddressOf alg1
    Call alg3()
End Sub

Public Sub alg3()
    Call m()
End Sub
```

Another option is to pass it as parameter:

```
Public Sub alg2()
    alg3(AddressOf alg1)
End Sub

Public Sub alg3(m As action)
    m()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example that runs the idea described above.

Simplified Console Code:

```
Public Module Module1

    Private Delegate Sub CoolDelegate()
    Private m As CoolDelegate

    Public Sub Main()
        Debug.WriteLine("Calling Alg1")
        Alg1()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Alg1()
        Debug.WriteLine("Alg1 Called")

        Debug.WriteLine("Calling Alg2")
        Alg2()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Alg2()
        Debug.WriteLine("Alg2 Called")

        m = New CoolDelegate(AddressOf Alg1)
        Debug.WriteLine("Calling Alg3")
        Alg3()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Alg3()
        Debug.WriteLine("Alg3 Called")

        Debug.WriteLine("Calling m")
        m()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Output:

```
Calling Alg1
Alg1 Called
Calling Alg2
Alg2 Called
Calling Alg3
Alg3 Called
Calling m
Alg1 Called
Calling Alg2
Alg2 Called
Calling Alg3
Alg3 Called
Calling m
Alg1 Called
Calling Alg2
Alg2 Called
Calling Alg3
Alg3 Called
Calling m
Alg1 Called
Calling Alg2
```

*(...Repeating till stack overflow...)*

It also can be modified to get rid of the local private variable. Here is another version...

```
Public Module Module1

    Private Delegate Sub CoolDelegate()

    Public Sub Main()
        Debug.WriteLine("Calling Alg1")
        Alg1()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Alg1()
        Debug.WriteLine("Alg1 Called")

        Debug.WriteLine("Calling Alg2")
        Alg2(AddressOf Alg1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Alg2(Caller As CoolDelegate)
        Debug.WriteLine("Alg2 Called")

        Debug.WriteLine("Calling Alg3")
        Alg3(Caller)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Alg3(Caller As CoolDelegate)
        Debug.WriteLine("Alg3 Called")

        Debug.WriteLine("Calling Caller")
        Caller()
    End Sub
End Module
```